# Should I build a website for my new employer?

Tags: new-job

I just landed this job that pays pretty good, I was referred to the job by a distance friend ( well wisher ). I an the assistant manager who recruited me did not have much to discus on the day of my interview since my resume spoke a lot for me.

I am supposed to sign this job document a week from now, my employer may have noticed in my resume that I have skills in IT but I bet they cared less since the job is purely engineering. Unfortunately I noticed they don't have a corporate website which I am skeptical about the reasons.

Is it a good idea to **ask why they don't have a website** and also **propose to build** one for free for them if their reasons are objectionable.

Comment: Building one for free sounds like a bad idea.  You don't want to set that precedent.

Comment: Its certainly a ok to ask why they don't have a website.  I would think on the answer given before offering up to build one.

Comment: Are you interested in working for them and are you interested in building the web site? If so, offer to build it as part of your "additional responsibilities as required". Not for free, but as part of the job.

Comment: Perhaps they don't have one because they don't care to have one. It's not really that unusual for a business to not have a website, plenty don't. Unless you're asked, I'd just leave it alone. I've found from personal experience that doing exactly what you propose can, oddly enough, offend people. Not only is it offering yourself up for free, but you're implying that something is wrong or lacking with their company, right after walking in the door.

Comment: Focus on doing the job you were hired to do.  Learn about the company culture.  After you've been there a bit, ask your supervisor why the company has no website.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing good would come from building a site for free.  It devalues your time.  If they don't want to pay for one (part of your job activities) it is not a priority and will be a political landmine.  No one will care until you are done and then no one will agree.

A simple simple mock up to show them you know how to build a simple page maybe.

Comment: +1 because "No one will care until you are done and then no one will agree" - this happens, definitely. I've had contracts fall apart because one person took up the task of "let's get us a website", and then when it started coming together everyone suddenly became project manager of the same project.

Comment: I would add to this that is you do it on company time as part of your job then its not for free.   Otherwise 100% agree.  ( and upvoted )

Comment: I don't really mind getting paid, I have never built a product of this nature but I am capable of. I just wan't to do something I have not done before ( building for an organization as large as they are ) it has it benefits

Comment: @Nexima360 There aren't really any benefits to be honest. I've built websites for mid-to-large size companies, and nobody cares. Website building isn't really appreciated as a skilled trade anymore since the market is completely saturated with capable individuals. Web apps are a different story, but a plain old website, no.

Comment: @Nexima360 You don't mind doing it for free now, but at some point you will decide you no longer want to spend the time and effort required to maintain the website in your free time. When that time comes, it will make you look bad, regardless of whether you have the right to say no or not.

Comment: @Nexima360 If you had already decided it has benefits then why did you ask the question?